# Saving Site Template for publishing portal in Office 365 SharePoint 13

Tags: office-365-develop-tool

I am trying to generate a wsp file for a publishing portal but I cannot find the feature in the site settings.

Previously the Save Site Template feature used to be visible in the site  setting for sites such as team site and blogs, but for publishing portal the feature is not present.

I have also tried to save the template using PowerShell but the message tells me the feature is not available in the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Publishing sites cannot be saved as site templates.  This is the case in 2010 anyway so I assume you are hitting the same issue.

Comment: We can create templates in SP2010 directly from the server or by using PowerShell but these features are not supported in Office365 ... thanks for your comment

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more precise and said it is not supported http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2492356 instead of cannot be done.  This is only for publishing sites.